# How to deregister a function from SignalR client?

Tags: signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

Consider the following code:

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/hub").build();

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (message) => {
    console.log("Once");
});

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (message) => {
    console.log("Twice");
});
```

Now when the server sends `ReceiveMessage` to the client, the browser's console contains... both `Once` and `Twice`. Apparently, both functions are invoked.

Problem is, in of my inexperience & lack of knowledge I assumed that registering a new function for the same command (`ReceiveMessage` in this case) will automatically repleace the previously registered function, if there was any. And I was writing my program with that assumption. I only had to verify this assumption once I started noticing bizzarre behavior of my program.

Can I somehow deregister previously registered handlers? Or should I rewrite my JS code with the assumption that I should only register one function per connection per command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [*all handlers can be unregistered with just the method name*](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/30a59f6df79014942620a65fb7d65f32b6b1246b/clients/ts/signalr/tests/HubConnection.test.ts#L353-L373).

```js
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/hub").build();

connection.off("ReceiveMessage");
connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (message) => {
    console.log("Once");
});

connection.off("ReceiveMessage");
connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (message) => {
    console.log("Twice");
});
```